# Is there any way to go to new page in different button input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<form id="signup">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." autocomplete="off">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." autocomplete="off">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." autocomplete="off">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number." autocomplete="off">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="addr" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number." autocomplete="off">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your password" autocomplete="off">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your password" autocomplete="off">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="mrgn-30-top">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-larger btn-block" onclick="rdt()">
                  Sign up as customer
                </button>
  </div>

  <div class="mrgn-30-top">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-larger btn-block">
                    Sign up as Shop Owner
                  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="redirect">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="file:///Users/megatron/Documents/Project/The_Isle_of_Kitchens/Login/login.html">Login Here</a></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I wanna go to a new HTML page when the user clicks the "Sign Up as Shop Owner" button. I used the  tag in that portion, but it's not working, how will I use the  tag in that division or is there any other way to solve it?
Just give suggestion to me the way to solve it.

Comment: Ok, and where is your question? So far you only told us what you want to do but have not asked any questions. Please read [ask]!

Comment: @tacoshy question updated!

Comment: Now you added that you don't understand what a form does. Still, not a single useful question that is within the scope of SO. What does a `form` do in your opinion? SO is not the right place to ask about fundamental basics that tutorials should teach you. First, you need to read up on how to establish a database connection and how to `insert` or `select` from the database.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Checkout the [different types of attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms_attributes.asp) you can use for `<form>` elements.

In particular:

- `target` will be of use, since it specifies *where* the from response will come back to. (Normally this is the page that you are on : `target="_self"`)
- `action` will be helpful if you want to specify a different endpoint to submit the `form` data to

Comment: Not useful for a poor question such as this. OP needs first to learn some basics about what a form is and what it does. Also, he needs to learn first how a database connection works and how to use `select` and `insert` with a database.  This question requires backend basics that are completely missing here.

Comment: @tacoshy ik how to use <a> tag, but here <a> tag is not working! that's why I'm looking for a solution.

Answer (score -2):

Using `target="_blank"`in as an attribute for an `<a>` tag will open the link in a new tab.

Example on here. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp